# Qual a real utilidade de docker-php-ext-configure e docker-php-ext-install?

Tags: docker

Estou dando os primeiros passos com Docker, logo veio a pergunta, o que é o 
**docker-php-ext-configure** e **docker-php-ext-install**?

Exemplo:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite
```

Não entendi qual o objetivo destes. Não seria o mesmo de utilizar o apt-get install pdo pdo_mysql...?

Comment: Não conheço de PHP, mas é possível que estes caras sejam utilitários que estão na imagem base do PHP para facilitar a instalação e configuração de dependências.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esses dois comandos são ferramentas para facilitar a inclusão de módulos PHP no docker, Eles fazem parte de todas as imagens oficiais do PHP e por isso padronizam a instalação dos módulos. https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Ao instalar um módulo PHP é necessário executar um conjunto de procedimentos que mudam dependendo de qual é o módulo, da versão do PHP, do servidor web utilizado e dos pacotes instalados anteriormente.

Por exemplo, considere o módulo bz2 no PHP7.2 sobre o Apache2 no Alpine Linux. Para ativá-lo é necessário que a linha "extension=bz2.so" esteja nas configurações do PHP.

Ao executar o comando 'docker-php-ext-install bz2', é criado um arquivo respectivo na pasta conf.d do PHP contendo a linha para sua ativação.

Ou seja, não basta que os pacotes estejam instalados para que um módulo funcione, o PHP ainda precisa de pequenas alterações no contêiner que variam de acordo com a imagem do PHP selecionada.